# angular2 input number error

Tags: angular, input

I'm trying to create a time picker component having hour, minute, second in separate inputs. This  should be controlled between 2 different timestamps for min and max.

Separate fields work ok, min and max work ok but input does not.

I have

```html
<input
  type = number
  name = hour
  [ngModel] = _hour
  (ngModelChange) = updateHour($event)
  [min] = _minHour
  [max] = _maxHour
  placeholder = 00>
```

When entering `88` sets maximum to `23` (as expected) then entering another `8` sets ngModel to `23` (as expected) but input displays `238`, (which is wrong)

I've done a plunker to 
https://plnkr.co/edit/XUWOim?p=preview

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be a limitation with the native <input type="number"/> element. It will only display error message on submit:
http://jsfiddle.net/TAftq/ (get from another stackoverflow topic). Tested in Chrome.
It seems that Firefox also does not restrict input values: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=365196

I suppose that you will need to use 3rd party component to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

1. Pass input element as parameter in updateHour function

   ```
   <input #hour
         type = number
         name = hour
         [ngModel] = _hour
         (ngModelChange) = "updateHour($event, hour)"
         [min] = _minHour
         [max] = _maxHour
         placeholder = 00>
   ```
2. Set input value to correct value( after validation)

   ```
   updateHour(value:string, hourElement: ElementRef){
         let intValue: number = Math.max(this._minHour, Math.min(this._maxHour, parseInt(value))) || 0;
         hourElement.value = intValue;
         this.time.setHours(intValue);
         }
   ```

   Don't forget to import ElementRef

   ```
         import {Component, NgModule, OnInit, ElementRef} from '@angular/core'
   ```

Comment: it's ugly but it warks. Thanks a lot!